# How to attach deck when ledger board will be too low?

Tags: deck

I'm building a (low) deck, and the siding is brick. I don't think attaching ledger board to brick siding is a good idea, it's not structural, even if I drill all the way through the brick, air gap and into the rim joist, the load will be on the brick, plus water penetration issues.

So I thought it might be possible to attach ledger board to the concrete foundation, and then somehow attach deck joists on top of ledger board? Is it possible at all? See photo how it looks now:
[image]

The distance from top of foundation to top of door threshold is exactly 12", so I was thinking 2x10 joists plus decking will bring the deck surface almost level with the indoor floor level.

I know I can build a freestanding deck, but I don't want to pour more footings than absolutely necessary. I'm in Ontario, so these have to be rather deep.

Comment: So do you have any pictures of how you did this? I have the same issue.
Thanks

Comment: @LeeBartnik sorry, pictures are tricky since it's all covered. What we did is excavated near the foundation and connected 6x6 posts with lag bolts to the concrete foundation. And the deck ledger board sits on these 6x6s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason at all that you can't install your ledger, then post up from it (or simply joist over it). You might still want to put a few fasteners through the upper rim joist to keep it snug against the brick, but they won't carry load. If the ledger needs to lap over the brick to achieve the correct height, space it out from the foundation wall with 1/2" or 3/4" treated plywood, as is appropriate.

That said, float your design past your local inspector (or a trusted builder) for approval. I can't see everything through the internet that might be relevant.