# Ledger board too low

Tags: framing, deck

[image]This has been [asked before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/111380/how-to-attach-deck-when-ledger-board-will-be-too-low) but without a detailed answer. I want to install a ledger board on the foundation, not the brick.

Can I run joists off the ledger board like normal, then in the opposite direction build another set of 2"*10" joists ontop of those ones?

[image]

Comment: A drawing of your plan, even if it's a "back of the envelope" sketch would go a long way toward explaining your plan.

Comment: There I just did a rough sketch. There would be blocking in-between every 16 inches as well. Thank you!

Comment: A ledger board attached to the foundation would have through bolts every foot or so, and all the joists would hang from hangers attached to it or sit on top of it. Your drawing shows a 2x10 'rim-joist' acting as a beam for all of the other joists (because you have them going the wrong way) which is likely *'insufficient to transfer load'*. I believe you can have a single ledger at the house, but the far side has to be doubled up. - A deck *built to code* 10" too low with 10" of extra stuff to make back up the height is fine. As drawn it is not to code.

Comment: If you're set on there not being a useless undercarriage, those 2x10s on the ends need to be beams. Prob 8x8s. ... You *must* run "joists off the ledger board like normal" and put blocking. Then if you *'fur it out'* another 10", that needs blocking too. And the decking is going to end up being perpendicular to the house and 4.5' long. If you can't get 10' decking, you're going to have a lot of 3.5' waste. - If they're 10' and they went the way they usually do, there'd be zero waste on a 10' long deck....

Comment: It seems like you just want to avoid touching the brick - why not just build the deck independent of the house?  Put a beam on posts offset from the house by 2", do the same 10' from the first one and then run your joists between it.  Save yourself the whole 10" structure you are proposing to build on top.

Comment: Then you have to dig holes instead of drilling them, which the OG OP didn't want to do.

Comment: Be cautious about answers with a single focus. I see many want to be pro answers that are not either pros and have limited experience that may not even be code compliant in different jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Frame challenge solution:

My code requires [8" x 4" x 1/2" Steel Angled Deck Brackets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/76069/23295) attached to the posts to support the doubled up ledger (edge beam). I'd use more of those attached to the foundation to support the ledger at the house, and then through-bolt it into the veneer for pullout.

I'm not sure how many you'd need as this is kinda ad-hoc. But if you laminated the ledger at the house (to double that up too), you'd need less... That may actually be a requirement for a ledger hung between, what is essentially in this case, pockets. So you need one every... w/e the max distance is between pockets for a ledger that's stood-off from the building. Presumably that's the same distance that your edge beam can be between posts. Which is never more than 8', so you need at least three.

[Page 32 of my code book](http://www.cityofchicago.org/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/Porch/Porch2011/RevPorch_Guide52611_Secured.pdf) shows it like you have drawn, but with those beams I'm talking about in the comment. And are probably assumed to be set into pockets of a masonry structure, but I don't think you want to do that to your foundation. As it is, my plan requires two ~1" holes drilled into concrete for every bracket, which violates the foundation's water-tightness. But it's above grade, so...

Comment: Just fyi: *edge beams* (the one furthest from the house) , *ledgers* (attached to the house), and *rim joists* (attached between those two) are all three different things.

Answer (score 0):

I understand not wanting to make a freestanding deck with all the footings involved. But since this is close to the ground, a floating deck will work fine. The rules vary somewhat by jurisdiction, so you need to check that you (a) can install a floating deck, (b) that your desired deck height is at or below the maximum height for a floating deck, and (c) determine whether or not you need any permits.

Many jurisdictions allow floating decks up to a particular size without any permit at all. That is in contrast to a regular deck which pretty much *always* requires a permit, for very good reasons.